# Sequence of non negative real numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of non negative real numbers such that $a_{n+m}\le a_n+a_m$ for all natural numbers $m$ and $n$. Prove that 
$$a_n\le ma_1+(n/m-1)a_m$$
for all $n\ge m$.

**Progress:** From the given condition we have $a_n\le na_1$.  Hence it suffices to show that
$$na_1 \le ma_1+(n/m-1)a_m$$
$$\implies{}ma_1\le a_m.$$ 
However the reverse is true. So its seems that the given inequality is much stronger than $a_n\le na_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it *is* much stronger. If, say, $a_2$ is strictly less than $2a_1$, then that lowers the upper bound on all later terms of the sequence.

Think about the problem intuitively first. Why is it true? Well, the $(\frac{n}{m} - 1)a_m$ is there because instead of adding successive $a_1$'s you can add $a_m$'s over and over, until you would have crossed $n$ - that means you can adding $a_m$ up to $\frac{n}{m}-1$ times. Then there's a little left over - what step size can we use for that part? How many steps could it take?

This is all very vague and based on an intuitive understanding of what's going on - the next step is to wrap it up in the formalism necessary to make a real proof. I'll leave that to you.